# Leaflet tilelayer showing image not found icon for missing tiles

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, leaflet, microsoft-edge

I am using Leaflet 1.0 for my interactive map. I have created my own tiles for the Netherlands, added them:

```
L.tileLayer('/gem/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {zIndex: 10})
```

Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. **Note: the layer conatains administrative boundaries, white coloured borders, therefor they are barely visible in the image.**

IE and Microsoft Edge are displaying these 'image not found' icons for all missing tiles.

[image: Tiles not found, IE and Edge]

Comment: what protocol is the site using? IE/Edge will block unsecured images. In IE you can go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes... the dev tool will then list blocked content, markup and security messages in the console tab when you open the dev tool. to avoid it use protocol-less uri's eg. //gem/foo/bar.png

Comment: The protocol is http, however some of the images are showing up. The only ones that are not showing up, are the ones that do not exist. By properly configuring the bounding boxes and zoom levels of my layer in leaflet, I managed to stop IE/Edge from requesting the unavailable images.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the bounds and zoom levels match the actual bounds / zoomlevels of the WMS Tilelayer. In that case IE/Edge nor any other browser will request these missing images from the server.

You can pass the options maxZoom, minZoom and bounds to your L.TileLayer object. Also there's this option: errorTileUrl, which is an URL to the tile image to show in place of the tile that failed to load.

For more info check:
[Leaflet Tilelayer WMS docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer-wms)